# NUXT3 Upload files to server/api before posting to external resource

Tags: javascript, upload, nuxt.js, nuxtjs3, nuxt3

I'm currently working on a NUXT3 project, we have a form that allows the user to upload files to FileMail.
It works as expected on dev with no errors, but when testing on production we get a 500 status code.

I've narrowed it down to the save function, as the login and initialise steps work on production.

I've added what I've got so far below, if anyone has any suggestions please let me know.

**form.vue**

```
    const save = async () => {

        let formData = new FormData()
        
        formData.append('transferid', form.transferid )
        formData.append('transferkey', form.transferkey )
        formData.append('transferurl', form.transferurl )
        
        for( let i = 0; i < files.value.length; i ++ ){
            formData.append('file', files.value[i] );
        }

        let requestOptions = {
            method: 'post',
            body: formData
        }

        await $fetch('/api/form/save', requestOptions).then((response) => {
            return response
        }).then((data) => {
            console.log(data)
            complete()
        }).catch((error) => {
            console.warn(error)
        })

    }
```

**save.post.ts**

```
    for (let i = 0; i < files.length; i++) {

        let formData = new FormData()

        formData.append('file', new Blob([files[i].data], {type: files[i].type}), files[i].filename)

        let requestOptions = {
            method: 'post',
            body: formData
        }

        await $fetch(`${transferurl}?transferid=${transferid}&transferkey=${transferkey}&runtime=html5&chunksize=5000000&thefilename=${ slugify(files[i].filename, { lower: true }) }&chunks=10&chunk=0&retry=0`, requestOptions).then((response) => {
            return response
        }).then(() => {
            console.log(`${ slugify(files[i].filename, { lower: true }) } Uploaded ✓`)
        }).catch((error) => {
            console.warn(error)
        })

    }
```

**Error Response**

```
{"url":"/api/form/save","statusCode":500,"statusMessage":"","message":"Invalid code point NaN","stack":""}
```

Tried restructuring the formData just incase the Blob was incorrect, rewrote the entire function and spent hours trying to figure out this issue.